# Is it possible to index a video on HTML5? Laravel

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

Is it possible to index the video with tags so that if I click on the time the video moves to the selected time? I created a view to help you understand... like the indexes they do on YouTube. Do you have any ideas?

I'm mostly looking in JavaScript, but if there is something in Laravel that could allow something like this or I don't know html5 itself thank you all very much in advance.

[image]

```
<div class="guida-frame4349">
    @foreach ($tutorial as $item)
        <div class="guida-c1">
            <div class="guida-frame4347">
                <div class="guida-frame4348">
                    <span class="guida-text">
                        <span>{{ $item->titolo }}</span>
                        <br>
                        <span style="color: rgb(104, 95, 95);">Min : </span>
                        <a href="">
                            <U style="color: rgb(23, 33, 179); font-size: 17px;">
                                {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($item->minuto)->format('i:s') }}
                            </U>
                        </a>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="guida-frame4346">
                    <span class="guida-text04"><span>Procedura:</span></span>
                    <span class="guida-text06">
                        {{ $item->descrizione }}
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
<div class="guida-video">
    <div class="guida-maskgroup">
        <video class="guida-rectangle15" controls preload="auto" autoplay>
            <source type="video/mp4"
                src="/videotutorial/{{ $video }}" />
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply.

Is there a tutorial somewhere that you know of? I'm looking for such methods but I can't find anything. Can you help me with some examples using my code?

Comment: Please take the [tour]. A question isn't "solved" until it has an answer posted and accepted. Your information is in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77612951/revisions) should you need it. Also see [ask]. You shouldn't tag titles.